# get label of biggest column charts in c#

Tags: c#, mschart

I've made a chart for the age range of people. I want to get the **label** of the largest and smallest column in the chart. And return zero if there were several large or small identical columns.

[image]

my code :

```
Series series = new Series();
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
series.Points.AddXY("15-20", age_set1);
series.Points.AddXY("21-25", age_set2);
series.Points.AddXY("26-30", age_set3);
series.Points.AddXY("31-35", age_set4);
series.Points.AddXY("36-45", age_set5);
series.Points.AddXY("46-55", age_set6);
series.Points.AddXY("56-65", age_set7);
chart1.Series.Add(series);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the `AxisLabel` you need to find the `DataPoint` that has the largest value..:

```
double max  = series.Points.Max(x => x.YValues[0]);
DataPoint dp = series.Points.Where(x => x.YValues[0] == max)
                            .First();
string label = dp.AxisLabel;
```

Note that there may be **several** points with this value!  If you omit the `First()` you can get a `List<DataPoint>` which you can then enumerate..

if you want to return "0" for that case you could write:

```
List<DataPoint> dps = series.Points.Where(x => x.YValues[0] == max)
                                   .ToList();
string label = dps.Count == 1 ? dps.First().AxisLabel : "0";
```